# Python Aiohttp: Regarding utility of the Session object

Tags: python, aiohttp

Here below are 1 working piece of code that scrape links from the website of interactive brokers.

In the [documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#make-a-request) of aiohttp they say to always use the aiohttp.ClientSession() object so that "sessions" are reused from one requests to another. But what i can see from the multiple requests example ([here for instance](http://terriblecode.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python/)) is that 1 session is created per request...? So what is the interest of that Session object?

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

exchanges_by_locs=[]
inst_type_dicts=[]
async def inst_types(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.text()
            html = lxml.html.fromstring(response)
            p=html.xpath('//*[@id="toptabs"]/ul/li')
            for e in p:
                inst=dict(inst_type=e.find('a/span').text, 
                          url='https://www.interactivebrokers.com'+e.find('a').attrib['href'])
                inst_type_dicts.append(inst)

async def inst_by_loc(inst):
    url=inst['url']
    print("start: ",inst['inst_type'])
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            doc = requests.get(url).content
            html = lxml.html.fromstring(doc)
            p=html.xpath('//*[@class="subtabsmenu"]/li')    
            for e in p:
                exchanges_by_loc=dict(loc=e.find('a/span').text, 
                          loc_url='https://www.interactivebrokers.com'+e.find('a').attrib['href'])
                exchanges_by_locs.append(exchanges_by_loc)
            print("complete: ",inst['inst_type'])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(inst_types(url))
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
        *(inst_by_loc(inst) for inst in inst_type_dicts)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

aiohttp's maintainer recommend re-using the session object when possible. It's a small performance trick.

Comment: Apparently the maintainer himself doesn't know how to go about creating a persistent session.